# Wie schreibt man Dezimalbrüche in Worten?

Tags: spelling, numbers

Man hat mich gefragt, wie man Dezimalbrüche in Worten schreibt.

Aber ich weiß es nicht und konnte auch nichts im Netz finden.

Schreibt man die Zahlen nach dem Komma einzeln? (z.B. eins Komma eins drei acht sechs)

Oder als Zahl? (eins Komma tausenddreihundertsechsundachtzig)

Oder ist beides möglich?

Vielleicht hängt es von der Zahl nach der Komma ab?

Comment: Du schreibst es genau so, wie du es sprichst. Es gibt keinen Grund, dies anders handzuhaben.

Comment: Ein Dezimalbruch ist etwas anderes als eine Dezimalzahl. Bruch: 1/25 --> ein Fünfundzwanzigstel und Zahl: 1/25=0.04 --> null Komma null vier.

Comment: @alk Das ist falsch, so wie es du es darstellst. Die Begriffe werden in niederer Mathematik synonym verwendet und in der höheren Mathematik spielen die Unterschiede keine Rolle mehr, weil beide Darstellungsformen äquivalent sind.

Comment: @alk, es mag sein, dass man das in der Schulmathematik anders handhabt, aber als Mathematiker wäre ich nicht auf die Idee gekommen, unter einem Dezimalbruch etwas anderes als die Dezimaldarstellung einer reellen Zahl zu verstehen, also etwa 1,1386. (Uh, etwas spät der Kommentar, sorry.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Es gibt an sich keinen Grund, eine Dezimalzahl mit Nachkommastellen überhaupt in Worten zu schreiben. Wahrscheinlich hast du deshalb nichts gefunden. Wenn, würde man eine Prozent- oder Promilleangabe daraus machen (0,087 = siebenundachtzig Promille) oder einen „glatteren“ Bruch (0,75 = drei Viertel).

Die wesentliche Ausnahme wäre ein „Meta-Zusammenhang”, wenn z.B. hier jemand fragt, wie man eine solche Zahlenangabe ausspricht. In dem Fall würde ich es so schreiben, wie man es spricht, also entweder die empfohlene und mathematisch sinnvollere Aussprache in einzelnen Ziffern

> 123,456 = hundertdreiundzwanzig Komma vier fünf sechs

oder die ebenfalls weit verbreitete Lesung in Pseudo-Zahlen:

> 123,456 = hundertdreiundzwanzig Komma vierhundertsechsundfünfzig

In jedem Fall beginnen die einzelnen Ziffern und Zahlen mit Kleinbuchstaben. Ausnahmen sind nur die großen Zahlen, die auch einen Plural bilden, also *Million*, *Milliarde*, *Billion* usw. (Aber Substantivierungen groß: *Vor der Acht kommt die Sieben.*)

Comment: Ich glaube, ich habe alles klein geschrieben. Meine Frage wurde aber korriegiert und neben den tatsächlichen Fehlern wurden auch die Zahlen in der Frage groß geschrieben.

Comment: Es gibt tatsächlich Gründe. Schecks, Quittungen, etc. haben häufig Felder "in Worten". Den Zweck dieser muss ich wohl nicht erklären, oder?

Comment: @rimrul: In Quittungsvordrucken ist üblicherweise vorgesehen, nur den Betrag in vollen Euro auszuschreiben. Daneben ist "Cent wie oben" vorgedruckt. Einen Scheck habe ich seit Jahren nicht mehr ausgestellt, würde aber "siebzehn Euro und neunzig Cent" schreiben, nicht "siebzehn Komma neun null Euro".

Comment: @chirlu: Ja, man kann die Cents auch separat aufschreiben oder auf sie verzichten,  aber es sind Gründe. Es gibt bestimmt auch noch andere.

Comment: Nach dem Komma werden Ziffern einzeln vorgelesen. Davon gibt es keine Ausnahme. Alles andere ist ein grober Formverstoß. Alternativ gibt es die Möglichkeit, Größenangaben in mehrere Summanden verschiedener Einheit aufzuteilen, z. B. zwölf Euro neunzig Cent. Das hat aber nichts mit der Sprechweise von Kommazahlen zu tun.

Comment: Ja. Die Komma vierhundertsechundfünfzig vereiteln auch meine Zustimmung.

Comment: Ich bleibe dabei, daß es in der Praxis (von Leuten, die keine Mathematiker o.ä. sind) nicht selten vorkommt. Wenn man nun eine Aufnahme transkribiert von jemandem, der „drei Komma vierzehn“ sagt, kann man nicht lügen und „drei Komme eins vier“ schreiben.

Comment: @Toscho: Doch, es gibt Ausnahmen, und diese sind auch kein Formverstoß: 12,56 km = zwölf Komma sechsundfünfzig Kilometer ist - zumindest in meiner Heimat Österreich - eine absolut gängige Form, diesen Wert auszusprechen. (Ich habe übrigens in Graz Physik studiert und bin Hobby-Mathematiker.) Die Variante »zwölf Komma fünf sechs« wird auch in Österreich häufiger verwendet, ist aber eben beileibe nicht die einzige. Frage ein paar Menschen in Österreich nach dem Wert der Kreiszahl pi, und du wirst sehr oft »drei Komma vierzehn« als Antwort hören.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Nur weil viele Menschen diese Variante sprechen, heißt das nicht, dass sie kein Formverstoß ist. Sprachregeln mögen deskriptiv statt präskriptiv sein, wissenschaftliche Regeln sind dies nicht immer. Und hier gibt es nunmal die präskriptive Regel, die Ziffern nach dem Komma einzeln auszusprechen.

Answer (score 9):

Gebräuchlich ist es, die Zahlen nach dem Komma einzeln anzuführen.
(z.B. eins Komma eins drei acht sechs)

Comment: und auch mathematisch richtig! `eins Komma dreizehn` ist nicht korrekt in Deutschland. Siehe auch http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komma#Zahlen